# Using MEL expressions to control particles, which in turn control joint rotation

Tags: rotation, particles, mel

I've used an expression to emit particles on the death of a first particle object and it works really well. What I want to do now is use the second set of emitted particles to drive joint rotation, again using expressions. 
So, the sum total of what I have now is:

```
    if (volumeAxis_nParticle1_nerveImpulseShape.age >= volumeAxis_nParticle1_nerveImpulseShape.lifespanPP) 
//if particle age is >= lifespan
{
vector $pos = volumeAxis_nParticle1_nerveImpulseShape.position; 
//determines where the particles are when they die
float $emitNum = 3; 
//determines how many particles will be emitted upon particle death ie 3
for ($i = 0; $i < $emitNum; $i ++) 
// for variable $i, start at 0 and if $i <emitNum then add 1 to it and execute the following commands, but if $i =3, then quit
{ 
vector $randVel = <<rand(-0.5,0.5), -1, rand(-0.5,0.5)>>; 
//determines the direction of the emitted particles in x, y, z
emit -o emitOnDeath_nParticle1_acetylCholine //emit the second particle object
-position ($pos.x) ($pos.y) ($pos.z) //where first particle object dies
-at velocity //now determine velocity
–vv ($randVel.x) ($randVel.y) ($randVel.z); //vector values (vv) for random velocity x, y or z
}; 
};
```

The next set of expressions I have is:

```
    if (emitOnDeath_nParticle1_acetylCholineShape.age < emitOnDeath_nParticle1_acetylCholineShape.lifespanPP) 
longMuscleController22.rotateY = 0;
else if (emitOnDeath_nParticle1_acetylCholineShape.age >= emitOnDeath_nParticle1_acetylCholineShape.lifespanPP) 
longMuscleController22.rotateY = -0.1;
```

This second expression does rotate the joint, but for greater control, what I really need is another command to quickly return the joint rotation to 0 again, ie relax quickly after a contraction. At the moment, the rotation only returns to 0 when the first expression starts again. I was thinking maybe another else if line, something to the effect that when the particle count =0 (ie once all the particles have died off when lifespanPP is exceeded), that rotate y = 0 again?

I tried this instead, using particle count:

```
    int $numPar = `particle -ct emitOnDeath_nParticle1_acetylCholineShape`; 
if($numPar == 0) 
longMuscleController22.rotateY = 0; 
else if($numPar > 0) 
longMuscleController22.rotateY = -0.1;
```

Maya says the syntax is correct, but it throws up all sorts of errors once it executes and doesn't move the joint. I'd really appreciate any advice please on how to use the second set of particles to control joint rotation, if you have any?

Thank you in advance for all your help and best wishes,

Maja